# How to Apply Rotation to Drilldown Lable in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Can you please take a look at [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hxua2Lpk/) and let me know how I can apply rotation to labels in drildown?

[image]

I tried adding `rotation:90,  like

```
        series: [{
        groupPadding: 0,
        pointPadding: 0,
        borderWidth: 1,
        rotation:90,
```

but it didn't do the job

Comment: You need to apply that in axis options, like xAxis: {labels:{rotation:-45}}

Comment: Thanks but I want to do this only in drilldown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can catch drillup / drilldown events and call update() on xAxis to rotate labels.

```
events:{
            drilldown: function(){
                this.xAxis[0].update({
                    labels:{
                        rotation: -90
                    }
                });
            },
            drillup: function(){
                this.xAxis[0].update({
                    labels:{
                        rotation: -45
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hxua2Lpk/2/

Answer (score 0):

You may use this

```
 xAxis: {
            type: 'category',
            labels: {
             rotation: -45 

        }
    },
```

Using rotation : any degree you want to rotate will rotate your axis labels